# How to get stream from Mongodb 3.6 $changeStream instead of pulling the cursor using $cmd.getMore?

Tags: mongodb

I am a mongodb driver developer.

Is any way to get a **stream** for the changes? Like websocket/sse, keep sending data without close it.

Below is the $cmd which sent to mongodb to get a new changes from the server (I am using mongodb-core@3.0.2)

‌
    {
       "getMore":"5293718446697444994",
       "collection":"event",
       "batchSize":1
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is any way to get a stream for the changes?

According to the official [MongoDB driver specifications](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications) for [ChangeStream](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/change-streams.rst#changestream), it is an abstraction of a `TAILABLE_AWAIT` cursor. You may choose to implement it as an extension of an existing tailable cursor implementation.

Extending an existing cursor implementation would provide benefits as you don't have to implement other behaviour/features that comes automatically with a cursor.

Comment: https://github.com/mongodb-js/mongodb-core/blob/3.0.0/lib/connection/commands.js#L70

mongodb-core hardcode awaitData to false. we have to wait for mongodb team to add the support for it.

Comment: updated url: https://github.com/mongodb-js/mongodb-core/blob/master/lib/connection/commands.js 

version 3.1.0-beta4 still hardcode this.awaitData = false;